# 3D Transform div

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I am trying to create a div that can be "rotated" in 3D by grabbing the edge using

```
transform: rotateY(# deg);
```

My current setup involves a div, filled with a background color and an additional invisible div that is 20px aligned to the left edge. I added an event handler, onclick a JavaScript function using getElementById is called which currently just sets the rotateY to 60deg.

HTML

```
<div id = "square">
    <div class="LeftRotate" onclick="rotateLeft()"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function rotateLeft() {
    getElementById("square").style.transform = rotateY(60deg);
}
```

Could anyone explain what is wrong with the code? It seems so simple but it does not work. Also I would like to build this into a more dynamic system so the div could actually be "rotated" dynamically (by the user), rather than just going to a position. Any advice? I was thinking about getting the change in the cursor, and using that in a for loop which increments the rotation of the window by the change in cursor.

Comment: First thing you would need to put the `rotate..` within qutoes because it is a string. Second, I think there should be a `document.get..`. Third, if the angle is not dynamic I would prefer using a class like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/t3qX7/) because of vendor prefixes being required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using the below code:

1.First thing is that the value is a string so should be given within quotes.

2.Second, the `transform` requires vendor prefixes to support older versions.

3.Third, it requires a `document.` in front of `getElementById`.

```
function rotateLeft() {
    document.getElementById("square").style["-webkit-transform"]= "rotateY(60deg)";
    document.getElementById("square").style["-moz-transform"]= "rotateY(60deg)";
    document.getElementById("square").style["transform"]= "rotateY(60deg)";
}
```

[**Demo with Inline Styles**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/t3qX7/1/) | [**Demo with Class**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/t3qX7/)

**Note:** Unless your rotation angles are dynamically generated, I would recommend using classes instead of inline styles.

**Bonus Sample:** This is a very rough sample on how to dynamically change the rotation angle based on input given by user in the text box. Just give a rotation angle (just numeric) in the text box and then click on the `div` with text.

[**Dynamic Rotation Angle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/t3qX7/2/)